# Given $U,V \sim R(0,1)$. Determine covariance between $X = UV$ and $V$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Given $U,V \sim R(0,1)$ independent.
>
> Determine covariance of $X = U \cdot V$ and $V$

About notation: $U,V \sim R(0,1)$ means random variables $U,V$ are equally / uniformly distributed from interval $0$ to $1$.

---

What need to calculate is $$\text{cov}(X,V) = E(XV) - E(X)E(V)$$

Now need to know what is $E(V)$ and what is $E(X) = E(U \cdot V)$

$E(V) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot(a+b)$ in this example we have interval $a=0$ and $b = 1$ so we have

$E(V) = \frac{1}{2}$

$E(U) = \frac{1}{2}$

Is this correct so far I don't know how is continued :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First noting that $U,V$ are independent uniform variables on $[0,1]$ we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[U] & = \mathbf{E}[V] = \int_0^1 v dv = \frac12 \\
\mathbf{E}[V^2] & = \int_0^1 v^2 d v = \frac13
\end{align*}

Then using the independence of $U,\, V$ we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[X] & = \mathbf{E}[UV] \\
& = \mathbf{E}[U] \mathbf{E}[V] \\
& = \frac12 \times \frac12 \\
& = \frac14
\end{align*}
whilst
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[XV] & = \mathbf{E}[ U V^2 ] \\
& = \mathbf{E}[U] \mathbf{E}[V^2] \\
& = \frac12 \times \frac13 \\
& = \frac16
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X,V) & = \mathbf{E}[XV] - \mathbf{E}[X]\mathbf{E}[V] \\
& = \frac16 - \left( \frac14 \times \frac12 \right) \\
& = \frac1{24}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have just one question, how you would calculate $E(X^2)$. This is not necessary here but I'm interested for know it because maybe I need example in test and know how do it correct. Is it 

$$E(X^2) = E((UV)^2) = E(U^2 \cdot V^2) = E(U^2) \cdot E(V^2) = \int_{0}^{1} u^2du \cdot \int_{0}^{1}v^2 dv= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$$

?

Comment: Yes planned to do that long ago but I just came back home, thank you a lot again! :)